# I'm creating a form in a module but when I try to add a radio group the title displays but not the options

Tags: 7, forms

```
$form['todo'] = array(                                                        
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#prefix' => '<div id="todo">',
'#suffix' => '</div>' . $image,    
'thot_dialog' => array(                                                     
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="thot_dialog">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
),
'add_thot' => array(                                                      
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="add-thot">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#title' => t('Add New Thot, Related to Current Thot'),
  'new_thot_nid0' => array(                                                
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#default_value' => "",                                              
  ),
  'new_thot_name' => array(              
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Name Your New Thot:',
      '#default_value' => 'Type Name Here',
  ),
  'new_thot_rel' => array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Select One:',
      '#options' => $t_rels,
  ),
  'new_thot_reverse' => array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => 'Reverse the direction?',
      '#attributes' => array('#id' => 'new-thot-reverse'),
  ),
  'new_thot_options' => array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Choose One',
      '#title_display' => TRUE,
      '#options' => array(0 => 'Create the Thot', 1 => 'Edit the Thot (Add text, etc.)'),
      '#access' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => 0,
  ),
  'new_thot_submit' => array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit Thot',
  ),
);
```

Comment: The strange thing is that if I simply change "radios" to "select" in the code above, I get a select box which works perfectly, with exactly the options I want for the radio buttons. 

I wonder if that gives anyone a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Your `#options` setting only has keys, but no values. You need something like

`'#options' = array(0 => t('Closed'), 1 => t('Active'));`

Example from [Radios form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#radios).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Just tried that, and it makes no difference, unfortunately. I'm open to any other suggestions--been beating my head against this wall for hours.

Comment: Well, if you follow the link above a little further, you can end up here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!poll!poll.module/7 You can expand the source code with "View source", and you'll find actual examples of Drupal Core using the above pattern. You probably just have a small spelling error somewhere. I suggest you try to compare your code with the core examples.

Comment: Forgive the repetition if you've already seen what I posted above, but The strange thing is that if I simply change "radios" to "select" in the code, I get a select box which works perfectly, with exactly the options I want for the radio buttons. So, if there's a spelling error, it would seem that it must be "radios"--which looks right to me. Do you know of any significant other difference between radios and select that might point to the problem? (I have compared the code to the poll example, and as far as I can see it's identical--which doesn't of course mean it is...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dealing with Drupal 7. Take a look at the [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#radios) for the radios element type.

Make sure **#access** evaluates to `TRUE` if you want to have it display on the page.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is Drupal 7. I've added the following line:

      `'#access' => TRUE,`

But it still doesn't display the options.

I really thought you had hit the nail on the head, too, but... no such luck.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting a #default_value to 0?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I just tried it. No difference. But it still works fine as a 'select'. Must be some fundamental difference I'm missing about radios...

Answer (score 0):

I ran this in a test module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['todo']['add_thot']['new_thot_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Select One',
    '#title_display' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array('a','b','c'),
  );
}
```

And this appears on all forms (as it should):

[image]

You have something else going on here outside of this code snippet I'm afraid. Could you give us more code to look at possibly?

Another idea would be to run that exact same test and see if that appears on your Node Edit forms. If it does, then something else is happening in your custom form that's breaking the radio.

Comment: Okay, I've added more context in the code above.

I've also checked other radios on the site, and made sure they were working correctly.

See anything amiss?

Comment: I ran your new sample code (with a couple tweaks for the variables I don't have) and it also showed the radios correctly. Strange! What's the $image in the #suffix?

Comment: It's an svg graphic. Thanks for taking all this trouble.

Comment: I just ran it without the #suffix line--still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little far fetched, but have you tried putting your keys in ''?

Like:

```
    'new_thot_options' => array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Choose One',
      '#title_display' => TRUE,
      '#options' => array('0' => 'Create the Thot', '1' => 'Edit the Thot (Add text, etc.)'),
      '#access' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => '0',
),
```

Like I said, a little far fetched.

Comment: You also might try putting your options into an array outside of your $form that you can call within the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but I have had the exact same issue / symptoms.
I forgot to use `drupal_get_form`, in my case it was not looking as this :

```
$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('my_form');
```

Answer (score -2):

i am getting the option for radio buttons. please check the above code or provide more detail what you want to achieve.

and you are missing one closing bracket for below code

```
'add_thot' => array(                                                      
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="add-thot">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#title' => t('Add New Thot, Related to Current Thot'),
  'new_thot_nid0' => array(                                                
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#default_value' => "",                                              
  ),
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. This *reads* more like a comment than an answer. if it's meant to be an answer, please edit it to make it clearer, OK?